# Imprimir resultados em um feed intercalando com espaços (linha em branco) na horizontal

Tags: php, mysql, while

Montei um feed de notícias que lê em um banco as informações, porém preciso que ao invés de cada linha ser impressa uma seguida da outra, preciso que seja dado um intervalo entre cada impressão com uma linha em branco (intervalo), para poder ter algo assim:

- noticia impressa 01 (percorre a tela da direita pra esquerda)
- intervalo (sem informação)
- notícia impressa 02 (percorre a tela da direita pra esquerda)

O código que estou a usar é este:

```
<?php 
//conexão + select 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($query)) { ?> 
<p class=""> 
 <ul class=""> 
  <li class=""> 
   <?php while($ln=mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
         $feed=$ln['desc_noticias']; 
   ?> 
   <?php echo $feed; ?> 
   <?php } ?> 
  </li> 
   <?php } ?> 
 </ul> 
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.marquee {
 width: 100%; 
 margin: 0 auto; 
 margin-top: 0; 
 overflow: hidden; 
 white-space: nowrap; 
 background-color: #20407B; 
 color: white;
 box-sizing: border-box; 
 animation: marquee 50s linear infinite; 
 -webkit-animation: marquee 50s linear infinite;
}
 .marquee:hover {animation-play-state: paused; -webkit-animation-play-state: paused; }

@keyframes marquee {
0%   { text-indent: 27.5em }
100% { text-indent: -105em }
}
@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
0%   { text-indent: 27.5em }
100% { text-indent: -105em }
}
```

Deve ser bem fácil, mas não estou conseguindo ver uma solução. Agradeço a ajuda!

obs.: as dicas que foram dadas até o momento fazem com que todos os registros apareçam junto, intercalados com linhas em branco, porém não é esta a solução que preciso, obrigado assim mesmo pelas considerações, no aguardo de +ajuda!

Comment: Mostra um pouco do seu codigo amigo

Comment: <?php
 //conexão + select
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query))
    {
    ?>
    <p class="">
        <ul class="">
            <li class="">
            <?php 
                while($ln=mysql_fetch_array($query))
                {
                   
                    $feed=$ln['desc_noticias'];
            ?>
            
                <?php echo $feed; ?> 
                
                <?php } ?>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </p>

Comment: Experimenta adicionar um `<br/>`, depois de retornar o resultado, desta maneira: `$feed=$ln['desc_noticias'] . "<br/>";`. Ainda assim o teu código parece estar incompleto, e não é possível fazer muito não sabendo onde está o resto.

Comment: Você pode criar um novo div, dentro do while(), depois da exibição do $feed, em branco com este espaçamento... e cada vez que surgir uma notícia, fará a impressão da noticia + espaçamento... ou faça então uma cor sim e outra não, de background, para diferir uma da outra

Comment: CSS:
    .marquee {width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 0; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; background-color: #20407B; color: white;
box-sizing: border-box; animation: marquee 50s linear infinite; -webkit-animation: marquee 50s linear infinite;
    }
    .marquee:hover {animation-play-state: paused; -webkit-animation-play-state: paused; }

    @keyframes marquee {
    0%   { text-indent: 27.5em }
    100% { text-indent: -105em }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes marquee {
    0%   { text-indent: 27.5em }
    100% { text-indent: -105em }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria dessa forma, para diferir uma da outra:

```
<?php 
//conexão + select 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($query)) { ?> 
<p class=""> 
 <ul class=""> 
   <?php 
     $linhas = 0; 
     while($ln=mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
         if($linhas%2==0) $cor = "#F5F5F5"; else $cor = ""; 
         $linhas++;
         $feed=$ln['desc_noticias']; 
   ?> 
  <li class="" style="backgrond-color: <? echo $cor; ?>"> 
   <?php echo $feed; ?> 
  </li> 
   <?php } ?> 
   <?php } ?> 
 </ul> 
</p>
```

Comment: Pessoal, grato pelas ajudas, porém o que está rolando é que destas formas indicadas todos os registros retornam de uma só vez, mas com as linhas intercalando em branco, porém o lance é o seguinte: este CSS marquee leva da direita pra esquerda, e o que eu preciso é que apareça um registro, depois o intervalo (linha em branco), depois o proximo registro, mas isso em linha.

Comment: Você vai precisar explicar melhor o seu problema... é impossivel alguem entender oque você precisa dessa forma... edite sua pergunta.. coloque a imagem de como esta mostrando os registro... coloque a imagem de como vc quer que seja... e outra... se o seu problema esta relacionado ao CSS  vc precisa colocar o codigo dele também.

Answer (score 0):

Isso deve resolver

```
    <?php 

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT"); 
    if(mysql_num_rows($query)) { 

    ?> 

<p class=""> 

    <ul class=""> 

        <?php 

        while($ln=mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
        $feed=$ln['desc_noticias']; 

        ?> 

        <li class=""> 

           <?php echo $feed; ?> 

        </li> 

        <li class=""> 

           <!-- linha em branco -->

        </li> 

        <?php } ?> 

    </ul> 

</p>

<?php } ?>
```